# android: divide string with punctuation and maintain punctuation with sentence in array

Tags: android, split

I have a sentence,
hello, What you are doing?How are you?
I wanted to split the sentence with characters such as .,?
I have achieved it using split function
and the output is:

```
arr[0]=hello
arr[1]=What you are doing
arr[2]=How are you
```

but I want the array as

```
arr[0]=hello
arr[1]=,
arr[2]=What you are doing
arr[3]=?
arr[4]=How are you
arr[5]=?
```

I have done this code

```
String text = "hello, What you are doing?How are you?";
        String[] arr= text.split("[\\.,!;?:\"]+");

        for (String str : arr) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general strategy to preserve text while also splitting on it at the same time is to use lookarounds.  Lookarounds *assert* logic, but do not actually *consume* any text.  They are basically zero width.  I split below using the pattern:

```
(?=[\\.,!;?:\"])|(?<=[\\.,!;?:\"])
```

This says to split if we lookahead *or* lookbehind and see a punctuation character.

```
String sentence = "hello, What you are doing?How are you?";
String[] parts = sentence.split("(?=[\\.,!;?:\"])|(?<=[\\.,!;?:\"])");
for (String part : parts) {
   System.out.println(part);
}

hello
,
 What you are doing
?
How are you
?
```

### Demo

You might also want to run `String#trim` on each term to get the exact output you want.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen Thank you very much.I works great.